# Flutter error when lauching application on physical device

Tags: android, linux, debugging, flutter, adb

everyone.

I've installed the Flutter and I got a problem when I launch a simple application on my device.

I did from the Visual Studio Code, but didn't work. So I executed from the command line with

```
flutter run
```

and also didn't work. There is the output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on XT1069 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       6.2s
Resolving dependencies...                                    4.5s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                   
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         11.6s
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                  5.0s
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Error launching application on XT1069.
```

I also tried the command

```
flutter clean
```

before run. No success.

The flutter doctor full log:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 0.9.4 at /home/valdinei/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision f37c235c32 (4 weeks ago), 2018-09-25 17:45:40 -0400
    • Engine revision 74625aed32
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/valdinei/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/valdinei/dev/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /home/valdinei/dev/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.28.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 2.19.0

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • XT1069 • 0013848438 • android-arm • Android 6.0 (API 23)

• No issues found!
```

PS: My device is already on debug mode and the screen even "wake up" when I try the command to run.
My application is the default that came when I created the project.
OS: Linux Mint 18.3

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try that on any other device or emulator?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Dude, a friend mine told the same thing. I didn't think about it before. I test here with an ASUS and worked. '-'
The problem is my smartphone. I don't know how to proceed. I'll search about it.